# Ionic3 - ion-list not rendering properly when coming back from other screen

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm developing application using `ionic version 3.18`. I've created `list` by using `ion-list` with `virtualscroll`. When I go to new screen pressing `fab (+) button` and coming back to this screen, `ion-list` starts behaving unexpectedly.

here's the code

```
<ion-list no-lines [virtualScroll]="partnerArray">
    <ion-item-sliding *virtualItem="let item; let i=index">
    <ion-item (click)="view(i)">
        <ion-avatar item-start>
        <ion-img class="image" [src]="item.imageUrl" style="height: 50px; width: 50px"></ion-img>
        </ion-avatar>
        <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
        <p>{{item.email}}</p>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item-options>
        <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="delete(i)">
        Delete
        </button>
    </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
```

Here's the [video link](https://vimeo.com/244031541) showing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in latest `Ionic 3.9.2`.

> When changing tab or navigate to a different page than the one
>   containing a virtual scroll component, virtual scroll is still running
>   and specifically the part that listens for window resize events. When
>   you resize the window in the other screen for some reason (open
>   keyboard, change orientation, resize browser), that event is triggered
>   in virtual scroll and tries to re-calculate the virtual scroll
>   component. Unfortunately all the numbers that it takes into account
>   then are wrong, as it is not visible.

This is the [**release notes (see the `3.9.0`)**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases):